# How to install Worklight on Tomcat application server

Tags: tomcat, ibm-mobilefirst

Can any one help me how to install worklight server with tomcat.I am using `worklight 5.0.5`. I installed `worklight server` with `tomcat`. when i am trying to open `worklight` console i am getting error like **"Requested resource not found"**.

Hello all,

```
publicWorkLightProtocol=http
# For default port leave empty
publicWorkLightPort=7000
publicWorkLightContext=/worklight

This is where tomcat was running.

/worklight  None specified  Worklight   false   0   
 Stop   Reload   Undeploy  ![enter image description here][2]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure that you followed all required steps of the installation procedure, please consider reading through following documents:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/c_installation.html

There is a whole section about deploying Worklight on Tomcat.

Comment: in that link there is no sufficient information for deploying please provide me meaning full information

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you are deploying on a remote server (Tomcat, Liberty, or WebSphere) you must have either the Worklight Consumer or Enterprise (paid) editions. The free Developer Edition only runs within eclipse. If you have one of the paid editions, you might want to consider getting help from the support portal: http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/overview

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide some more information, such as the steps you took to install it, url you are trying to reach, etc.

A couple of things that you may look at:

1. Make sure you started the server.
2. Take a look at the WL logs to make sure that side of things is running properly.
3. Make sure you can access other apps in your Tomcat server.
4. Make sure your worklight.properties files are set up properly.
5. Make sure you are including the port (normally) 9080, and that you are putting the correct URL.

**EDIT** after question changes:

I am pretty sure your issue is the port. The standard Tomcat port is 8080, I believe WL automatically sets port 9080 (See [Tomcat Default Port](http://www.rescarta.com/index.php/rcsoft/rcfaqssec/13-rcwebfaq/35-tomcatport.html)

I would either change the Tomcat port ([How To Change Tomcat Default Port ?](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/))

Or change the WL port, I believe this is done here:
`/opt/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/WEB-INF/classes/conf/worklight.properties`

If this is the first time you'll be going into the `WEB-INF` folder, you'll need to open up the `worklight.war` file.

Comment: when i am starting the server i am getting error in startup.bat

Comment: where can i find the WL Logs

Comment: SEVERE: The web application [/worklight] appears to have started a thread named
[TaskCoordinatorTimer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.this is my error in startup.bat

Comment: Your logs should be in /opt/IBM/Worklight/server/whatever you named it/usr/servers/worklightServer/logs. Make sure all the ports are correct in /opt/IBM/Worklight/server//whatever you named it/usr/servers/worklightServer/server.xml. Also, make sure the ip and double check all info in /opt/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/WEB-INF/classes/conf/worklight.properties.

Comment: can u give your email id i will send log files

Comment: I would post them here, that way others can comment on them. And if someone runs into the same issue they can search by statements in the error logs. There should be nothing in the logs that is proprietary or that will compromise your security. As far as I know IP addresses and the like and not printed in WL logs.

Comment: i configured all the things but still same problem thats way i dont know how to attach files in this site

Comment: You can't attach files. Just copy and paste the relevant parts into your question. You should be able to edit it.

Comment: i changed my question once check it

Answer (score 0):

You really do need to specify which Worklight edition you are using (Enterprise, Developer?).

if you choose to not-use the IBM Installation Manager and you have the Enterprise edition then you also have the Worklight Java EE .jar file.

These instructions are only for the Worklight Server for the sake of simplifying matters for now:

1. Extact Tomcat
2. Place the Worklight Java EE .jar file in the \lib folder
3. Place a database connector in the \lib folder as well (this can be downloaded at the vendor website)
4. In Worklight Studio, create your project and configure your server in worklight.properties (set the context root only). Finally, take the .war file from the \bin folder (make sure to stop the Worklight Server (right-click on the project >> stop server) so that port 8080 will be freed)
5. Start Tomcat, go to the manager page and deploy the .war file
6. Visit `http://localhost:8080/yourContext/console`

If you are using the IBM Installation Manager:

1. Open the IM, go to preferences and enter the repository
2. Follow the installation, set database and add its connector (as mentioned in the steps above)
3. Choose Tomcat as your application server (when using the IM the default port is 9080 as opposed to 8080 in the other type of installation)

You are now basically done. Do the same as steps 4 to 6 for your own project.
Note that the IM installs a default Worklight .war file, you may want to delete or undeploy it before putting yours. (when creating your own .war, make sure to set the port to 9080 this time).